# how to launch resident vid player from mobile site

Tags: html, mobile, jquery-mobile, html5-video

im trying to launch the resident vid player in a phone from a url on a mobile site
and having a tough time doing this
there are lots of complexities

1) the vids are on amazons cloudfront 
2) they are signed and streaming
3) i want to write one codebase and have it work for both iOS and android

so ive got the signed and streaming bit to work on the normal desktop site
and using flowplayer

in order to keep to the one codebase idea
im using html5/jquery mobile

so whats the html5 that will launch the vid player for both platforms
is there even such a thing

thanks so much for your help

Comment: This could easily be figured-out with some Google-time. Search for `html5 javascript video player`. Or change `javascript` to `jquery` if you want a jQuery specific resource.

Comment: @jasper - actually not really - the answer is: html5 is a little too young to handle what i want it to do.  well i guess youre sorta right - since i had to google and experiment for a few weeks to come to this conclusion

Comment: You can play streaming video files in a `<video>` tag but I don't know about opening the `native` video player on a device. So HTML5 can do this, but you've got to use your own UI for the player (the Google search I recommended will come up with a few free players that have nice UIs already).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout jw player http://www.longtailvideo.com